# D3: Can I have an svg transition based on items in a list?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I would like to take a list...

```
var data = [100, 200, 300] // arbitrarily long
```

... and transition an element across the screen based on each list item. For example, I would like to send a dot first to [100,100], [200,100], [300,100]. Is there a way to do this with data joining?

Right now, I have have a solution that works, but it works in what seems to be a very un-D3-ish way: using a counter to iterate through a list, and using no data-binding. Excluding the CSS, here's the code:

```
<svg>
  <circle/>
</svg>


<script>

var data = [100,200,300]

var circle = d3.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("r",20)
    .attr("cy",100)
    .attr("cx",0)

var count = 0

repeat()

function repeat() {
  var run = circle
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("cx", function (d) {return data[count]});

    count++

  if (count < data.length){
    run
      .each("end", repeat);
  }   
}

</script>
```

Shouldn't there be a way to do this with data binding? I'd love to do this the right way, but for now this is all I can figure out just to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Using this as a reference: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1125997

I'm not convinced this is the best way to do it, because it still relies on an external variable `count`, which is not very D3.

Note the array structure of `data`.

https://jsfiddle.net/e51rzkth/4/

```
var data = [[[100,100],[200,100],[300,100]]]

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
  .attr("width", 400)
  .attr("height", 400)

var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("r",20)
    .style("fill", "red")

var count = 0

circle
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .delay(250)
    .on("start", function repeat() {
        d3.active(this)
          .transition()
          .attr('cx', d=>d[count][0])
          .attr('cy', d=>d[count][1])
          .transition()
            .on("start", repeat);
            count++;
      });
```

For funsies, an example with multiple circles, each with their own path.

https://jsfiddle.net/e51rzkth/3/

Comment: Yes this works. Is there a way to do this without a counter? It seems like such an elementary D3 problem. Bostock? Where are you?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could enter/append circles based on the data in the array, and then set cx based on it's data. Also, you can achieve the staggering by basing the transition delay on the data point's index, eg https://jsfiddle.net/65aeo5q5/ :

```
var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("r",20)
    .attr("cy",100)
    .attr("cx",0)
    .style("fill", "red")

var delay = 1000;

circle
    .transition()
    .duration(delay)
    .delay(function (d, i) {return i * delay;})
    .attr("cx", function (d) {return d;});
```